# wget ignores video files

Tags: linux, wget

A friend of mine put up a bunch of mkv files on a public server, how can i download them all with one wget command?

I have tried

```
wget -r [path]
```

which simply grabs the index file, robots.txt and skips the mkvs. I also tried

```
wget -r -A.mkv
```

If i try getting a individual file directly it works fine, what am i doing wrong here? The man page is very long so possibly i just skipped the relevant option in which case I apologise.

Comment: possibly... I'm not really interested in creating a whole different account on a site I will barely use when there should be enough overlapping knowledge to answer this fairly simple question right here. You can't compartmentalise everything!

Comment: @Ollie, that's not how it works.  It takes almost no effort to link your current OpenID to the other site (and you get 100 rep on the new site as a reward).  The rules are there to keep BOTH sites useful and less cluttered with "uninteresting" questions for the audience.

Comment: Does `[path]` list all the `.mkv` files as links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: Your answer is here: http://www.robotstxt.org/

The man page for wget has a workaround, but it is not a nice thing to ignore robots.txt, so I'm not recommending it (you can look it up yourself). You could verify whether this is the actual problem by viewing the text

```
curl http://somedomain.com/robots.txt
```

Comment: Yep had "Dissalow /" I asked him nicely if he minded me ignoring his robots and got the goods. Thanks.